# Abrir nova página somente o topo da página principal

Tags: html

Eae galera!

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento web e gostaria de tirar uma simples dúvida. Como faço para abrir somente o topo da página. Por exemplo:
Tenho a página principal com diversos conteúdos, inclusive um menu e slide.
Eu criei uma página onde será um artigo por exemplo. Como puxar somente esse menu e slide dessa página principal?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: cria um novo ficheiro html e copia da pagina atual a parte do codigo que quer neste caso somente o menu e o slide, e também o fecho das tags que deverá estar no final do codigo. Depois abres a pagina manualmente, ou podes referencia-la através de um link ou um botão por exemplo

Comment: Cara a sua pergunta ficou meio confusa, mas se vc que repetir seu menu em outras páginas, porém tendo apenas um arquivo vc pode usar o Includ do PHP. Assim vc tem o menu.html que vc usa o PHP para fazer o include em qualquer pagina que quiser. Se precisar mudar algo no menu.html ele sera atualizado em todos os lugares onde está "includado"

Answer (score 0):

Dá para vc fazer isto usando o método **load** do jQuery.

**No seu HTML:**

> Vamos partir de que vc já tenho uma página com o menu e o slide e aqui é outra página onde vai ser carregado esta página com o seu menu e slide.

```
<div id="menu-slide"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

> Nesta outra mesma página vc carrega dentro desta div (menu-slide) a página que tem só a parte do menu e do slide.

```
$("#menu-slide").load(pag-menu-slide.html);
```

Mais informações [veja aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load_callback).